# I just want to input a random number into the middle of my string

Tags: python-2.7

I just want to make it so that my generator generates monsters with a number of limbs between 1 and 100. I don't know why the self.numbers isn't working. I keep getting an invalid syntax error with the print statement in self.numbers.

```
import random

from random import randint

class Monster(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.names = random.choice(["Michael", "Amy", "June", "Margaret"])
        self.appearances = random.choice(["a beautiful", "a hideous", "a transparent", "a toxic"])
        self.animals = random.choice(["dog", "cat", "bird", "fish"])
        self.attributes = random.choice(["that can fly.", "that speaks in a human voice.", "that twists unaturally.", "that is too hot to touch."])
        self.features = random.choice(["arms", "legs", "tentacles", "heads"])
        self.numbers = print random.randint(1, 100)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(["The Human", self.names, "is here,", self.appearances,
                         self.animals, self.attributes, "It has", self.numbers,
                         self.features,])

# Create 5 unique monsters
M1 =  Monster()
M2 =  Monster()
M3 =  Monster()
M4 =  Monster()
M5 =  Monster()

# Prints the descriptions of the monsters:
print M1 
print M2  
print M3 
print M4 
print M5

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: you can make a string out of a number

    f>>> from random import randint
>>> randint(1,100)
72
>>> str(randint(1,100))

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
self.numbers = print random.randint(1, 100)
```

with

```
self.numbers = str(randint(1,100))
```

the print function will print into the shell and will not create a string. What you need is to convert your randomly generated number to a string using function str()

Your code:

```
import random
from random import randint

class Monster(object):

    def __init__(self):
       self.names = random.choice(["Michael", "Amy", "June", "Margaret"])
       self.appearances = random.choice(["a beautiful", "a hideous", "a transparent", "a toxic"])
       self.animals = random.choice(["dog", "cat", "bird", "fish"])
       self.attributes = random.choice(["that can fly.", "that speaks in a human voice.", "that twists unaturally.", "that is too hot to touch."])
       self.features = random.choice(["arms", "legs", "tentacles", "heads"])
       self.numbers = str(randint(1, 100))

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(["The Human", self.names, "is here,", self.appearances,
                     self.animals, self.attributes, "It has", self.numbers,
                     self.features,])

# Create 5 unique monsters
M1 =  Monster()
M2 =  Monster()
M3 =  Monster()
M4 =  Monster()
M5 =  Monster()

# Prints the descriptions of the monsters:
print M1 
print M2  
print M3 
print M4 
print M5

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

and result

```
The Human Margaret is here, a hideous fish that can fly. It has 65 arms
The Human Michael is here, a toxic fish that is too hot to touch. It has 75 heads
The Human Margaret is here, a transparent dog that can fly. It has 23 tentacles
The Human Margaret is here, a transparent dog that is too hot to touch. It has 64 arms
The Human Margaret is here, a hideous bird that twists unaturally. It has 46 heads
Press ENTER to exit
```

Comment: I gotta wait 6 minutes to answer the question, but your answer worked perfectly, thank you very much.

Comment: If it works you can accept the answer. For future, add the error description: my python gives me the syntax error and highlights the function print. It will give some insight into what is going wrong. Also, include the version of python, OS and other information that might be helpful. And good luck with learning Python. further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask